# Composition in c++, cannot get the expected result

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, coding-style

I have a problem in composition, I cannot get the expected output, please help me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class something{
int length;
public :
something(){length = 0;}
something(int l){length = l;}
void setLength(int l){length = l;}
int getLength(){return length;}
};

class person{
int age;
something obj_s;
public:
person(int i){age = i;}
void setS(int length)
{
    something temp(length);
    obj_s = temp;
}
something getS(){return obj_s; }
};

int main()
{
person p(20);
cout<<p.getS().getLength()<<endl;
p.getS().setLength(20); //--------change at here---------
cout<<p.getS().getLength()<<endl;

//--------------------------------------------------------

person w(20);
w.setS(5);
cout<<w.getS().getLength()<<endl;
w.getS().setLength(20); //--------change at here---------
cout<<w.getS().getLength()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The Output is :

```
0
0
5
5
```

why is not : (expected output)

```
0
20
5
20
```

If I want the expected output, what should I do ?

Comment: What did you discover when you ran this in the debugger?

Comment: Also, I only see two uses of `cout`; where do you get 4 lines of output from?

Comment: hint: `getS()` returns a *copy* of a `person`'s `something`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function

```
something getS(){return obj_s; }
```

should return a *reference*

```
something& getS(){return obj_s; }
```

because you intend to change the value in-place.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can *accept* this answer by clicking on the green check mark. That will indicate that this is the correct solution.